# How to fix istringstream compiler error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have some existing code that compiles fine with Visual Studio 2010 but gives an error with Visual Studio 2013.  The code simply extracts a string from an istringstream and checks whether the conversion was successful or not:

```
bool okFlag = false;
istringstream s;
string myStr;

<snip>

okFlag = s >> myStr;
```

The error is:

`error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'bool'`

I guess that in C++11, the return type of the conversion is not bool.  What is the correct way of doing it?  Is it possible to have code that satisfies both VS2010 and VS2013?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11 [`basic_ios::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is `explicit`, while the C++03 user defined conversion to `void *` was implicitly convertible to `bool`. To fix your code you need to explicitly cast the result.

```
okFlag = static_cast<bool>(s >> myStr);
```

Note that `explicit bool` conversion operators will still implicitly convert to `bool` in contexts where a boolean result is expected, such as the conditional expression in an `if` statement. That's why the code below still compiles without having to add a cast.

```
if(s >> myStr) {         // here operator bool() implicitly converts to bool
  // extraction succeeded
}
```